# Нужно ли ставить запятую перед «почти»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, причастный-оборот

Нужно ли ставить запятую перед "почти" в этом предложении? Если да, то почему?

**Среди лесной всячины сверкнула слюдяными лепестками любка, почти не замечаемая ребятишками.**

Comment: Вы даже не посмотрели мой ответ? Я же старался...

Comment: Если вас удовлетворил мой ответ, пожалуйста, примите его.

Answer (score 3):

Эх-эх, как у нас любят ради "пунктуационного натаска" кромсать классиков!

[В. П. Астафьев. Последний поклон](http://www.astafjev.ru/content/view/432/457/):

> Ниже по склону в сырости кипунов все растет еще пестрей, и вот *среди вольно растущей лесной всячины сверкнула слюдянистыми лепестками любка, редко у нас произрастающая и почти не замечаемая ребятишками,* избалованными множеством цветов ярких, крупных, как бы выставляющихся напоказ друг перед другом.

Конечно же, в этом "обгрызанном" предложении перед наречием [*почти*](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8) нужно поставить запятую, так как оно [наречие] является началом причастного оборота, следующего за определяемым словом [***любка***](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)) (это такое растение, думаю, не каждому школьнику известное):
*любка, почти не замечаемая ребятишками.*

[Когда причастный оборот выделяется запятыми?](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/kogda-prichastnyiy-oborot-vyidelyaetsya-zapyatyimi.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%2C%20%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8,%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D1%81%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8.)

Answer (score 2):

Да, запятую нужно ставить, поскольку **причастный оборот, стоящий после определяемого слова, обособляется запятыми.**

"Любка" — определяемое слово, то есть слово, которое будет определяться, описываться.

"Почти не замечаемая ребятишками" — причастный оборот, который относится к предшествующему ему слову, то есть он **стоит после определяемого слова** (любка), а потому обособляется. Если бы предложение этим оборотом не завершалось, мы бы поставили запятую и после него, а так эту закрывающую оборот запятую поглотила точка.

Если в вашем предложении причастный оборот поставить перед определяемым словом, то запятые будут не нужны:

***Среди лесной всячины сверкнула слюдяными лепестками почти не замечаемая ребятишками любка.***

Правда, выглядеть это дело будет грузно и нескладно, но это уже совсем другая история.