# О правильном употреблении союза «не только, но и»

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, однородные-члены

А еще этот вопрос о редактировании классики.

Дано предложение:

*Солнце блестело **не только на распустившейся листве и молодой траве, но и на всходах хлебов(,) и на ряби быстрой реки**.*  Нужна ли указанная запятая?

Я посмотрела источник:

Глава 25 — Хаджи-Мурат (Толстой Л. Н., 1904)

*С утра был туман, но к завтраку погода разгулялась, и солнце блестело **и на только что распустившейся листве, и на молодой девственной траве, и на всходах хлебов, и на ряби быстрой реки**, видневшейся налево от дороги.*

Таким образом, автор используют не двойной, а обычный повторяющийся союз И… И для четырех однородных членов.

И вопросы:

1. Можно ли вообще использовать двойной союз,  не искажая при этом авторский текст?
2. Если все-таки это сделано в учебных целях, то нужна ли указанная запятая?
3. Возможны ли варианты при решении подобных предложений, то есть может ли автор по своему усмотрению ставить или не ставить запятую?

Comment: Что значит ‟дано предложение”? Оно из какой-то книги? Вы его придумали? Кто-то другой его придумал? Кто-то переделал авторское предложение, и вы спрашиваете, можно ли так делать?

Comment: Предложение взято, как я полагаю, из учебных материалов, а нашла я его на сайте Большой вопрос", где оно обсуждалось. Разумеется, происхождение текста легко можно узнать из ИНтернета, что я и сделала.    http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3911975-gde-dolzhny-stojat-zapjatye.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, в данном случае запятая факультативна и зависит от смыслового объединения.
Выше привели пример из Булгакова, где запятая не стоит, а вот пара примеров, где запятая в подобных случаях стоит:

- Мне передавался мамин священный ужас перед торчащим без дела инструментом, словно он мог служить укором не только маме, но и мне, и даже когда-нибудь моим детям. (Рубина)
- Стали проявляться у нее и кое-какие подозрения, что среда, где она увязла, не только веселящаяся, но и жуликоватая, и развратная. (Амфитеатров)

Comment: Отличный ответ! И примеры подобраны подходящие. Сам двойной союз  НЕ ТОЛЬКО...НО И двучленный (закрытый), но его части могут включать однородные ряды любого вида (об этом, кстати, говорится в Грамматике-80). Выбор же автор делает по смыслу.

Answer (score 1):

Свое отношение к кромсанию реальных предложений я уже высказывала, и не единожды (например, [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462368/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8/462397#462397)).

В авторском предложении однородные дополнения *на листве, на траве, на всходах, на ряби* являются равноценными "в охвате солнечным блеском".

При использовании двойного сопоставительного союза «не только… но и...» акцент, как мне кажется, смещается на последние два члена; в тексте учебного предложения они отделены (выделены) и становятся более значимыми. А это меняет смысл, меняет толстовскую задумку.
(Кстати, есть еще и ["солнце блистало"](http://oplib.ru/dom/view/146605_prostoe_predlozhenie).)

Конечно же, теоретически большое предложение можно разделить на два, поставив точку после "разгулялась". Вот от этого значение практически не изменится, а получатся две относительно самостоятельные конструкции.

Указанная запятая, считаю, не нужна, так как первый союз «и» относится к двойному союзу, а второй является самостоятельным союзом между однородными членами (*на всходах **и** на ряби*).

Через четверть часа чрезвычайно поражённая публика **не только** в ресторане, **но и** на самом бульваре **и** в окнах домов, выходящих в сад ресторана, видела, как из ворот Грибоедова... [М. А. Булгаков. Мастер и Маргарита, часть 1 (1929-1940)]

Comment: А я хочу написать так: Солнце блестело не только на распустившейся листве и молодой траве, но и на всходах хлебОв, и на ряби быстрой рекИ (повторяющийся союз И, перечислительная интонация).   Можете ДОКАЗАТЬ что это неправильно?  К примеру, я видела такое предложение: Он не любил не только супы, но и каши, и холодец, и сухофрукты.  Здесь тоже перечисление, открытый ряд. Можно еще что-нибудь добавить из того, что не любил.

Comment: Извините, но мне нечего доказывать. В этом кургузом, обкорнанном — искусственном! — предложении нет места никакому замыслу и никакому выбору. Вы сами сказали, что предложение построено для учебных целей. Так вот: для **учебных** целей запятая не нужна. Куда там, какой там неизвестный автор (перестраиватель классики) собирался поставить запятую, какие там члены пытался обозначить с помощью перечислительной интонации — никому неизвестно. Известно только одно: авторское предложение безнадежно испорчено. И я постаралась объяснить — почему. Вы ведь *об этом* спрашивали в первую очередь.

Comment: Я хотела услышать единственно правильный ответ: мы строим подобные ряды однородных членов по семантическим признакам, поэтому свободны в выборе последней запятой (это указано в грамматике). Вы же считали, что она там не нужна, потому что все так привыкли считать (вариант более частотный, поэтому его принимают за аксиому). Вот эта ограничение меня не устраивает. Ну а в целом спасибо за ваше мнение, я его услышала. Ответ принят, у меня по этой теме больше нет вопросов.

Comment: И по поводу классики. Учить детей грамотному письму тоже надо, и учить по хорошим текстам (не самим же их придумывать).  Иногда можно использовать часть длинного предложения из авторского произведения, вот только структурными перестройками заниматься не надо, причем никакими.

Comment: Извините еще раз, но я не вижу никакого смысла в Вашем последнем комментарии: Вы же просто пересказали то, о чем говорилось в моем ответе.  И еще: *А я хочу написать так...* "Дык" и пишите, принимайте абстрактное решение по абстрактному предложению. Вы вольны написать так, как Вам угодно, но чтобы принять пунктуационное решение, нужен контекст, обрамление. А вот его-то у этого искусственного предложения нет.

Comment: Римма, поздравляю вам с наступающим Новым годом. Расскажите лучше, какая у вас волшебница-зима. А то мне грамматика надоела…

Comment: Зима у нас — что надо, удивит любого! Прибалтийская погода ведь известна своими *непредсказуемостями*. Я часто бываю на природе — у меня появилась новая живность, взятая из приюта (доходяга-то мой умер). Прилетели снегири; сегодня видела лису. Люблю снег, когда он падает клочками или почти перьями. Сейчас морозно и безветренно.

Comment: Спасибо!  Мое детство прошло на природе, в яблоневом саду, а рядом лес. Иногда такой тоскливой кажется городская жизнь. К нам тоже прилетали снегири, а здесь только галки и голуби. Уток много, ходят иногда по парку пешком. Но куда они деваются в морозы - не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант объяснения отсутствия запятой в предложенном для анализа примере.

Первая часть союза присоединяет **первую** **пару** однородных членов предложения, вторая часть союза - **вторую пару**. *Не только* ПАРА 1, *но и* ПАРА 2. Однородные члены внутри пар соединены "своим" союзом И.

***Солнце блестело не только на распустившейся листве и молодой траве, но и на всходах хлебов и на ряби быстрой реки.***

Comment: Это стандартное применение конструкции, которое пользователи считают единственно правильным. Я бы даже  сказала, устоявшееся мнение, которое всеми повторяется без указания на источник информации. В каком академическом справочнике по грамматике это написано, вы его можете процитировать?

Comment: Кстати, сам двойной союз не просто делит ряд на пары, а с вполне определенным смыслом. Об этом можно почитать в Русской корпусной грамматике..3.2.3. Градационные союзы: Союз не только... но и указывает на то, что оба конъюнкта соответствуют действительности, в противоположность ожиданиям Адресата, который, по мнению Говорящего, мог бы, исходя из своих знаний, считать, что ей соответствует только первый:  http://rusgram.ru/Сочинительные_союзы 3.2.3. Градационные союзы:  В этом тоже недопустимость правки классики, так как появляется дополнительная семантика, которой не было в тексте.